# how to change process (application) priority from Normal to Low Programmatically in Golang

Tags: go

How to change Process Priority Class Programmatically in Golang?
I have CPU intensive task and I want system and user programs have higher priority so my Golang application run only when the system is idle, or better using free CPU cores.

Like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391449/set-process-priority-of-an-application
But in Golang.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process's scheduling priority is a OS and platform dependent setting, so you might be want to look at the `syscall` package:

```
func Setpriority(which int, who int, prio int) (err error)
```

This works on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Example program that works on windows:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights
const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = windows.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | windows.SYNCHRONIZE | 0xffff

func SetPriorityWindows(pid int, priority uint32) error {
    handle, err := windows.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, uint32(pid))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer windows.CloseHandle(handle) // Technically this can fail, but we ignore it

    err = windows.SetPriorityClass(handle, priority)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "hello.py")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set priority to above normal
    err = SetPriorityWindows(cmd.Process.Pid, windows.IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
}
```