# Possibility to NOT hook all available CPU power?

Tags: windows, go, concurrency, goroutine

I know, most of the beginners of go ask how to have performative go-routines / concurrency, this point I passed a few weeks ago. :-)

I have a real fast trans-coder that uses every cycle available of my 4+4 (i7 HT) CPU. It reads a file into a slice of pointers to structs, does calculations on these and writes the result back to disk. I am using bufio. I am coming from VB so the performance of Go is unbelievable.

I tried to add minimal sleeps (via time.Sleep()), but that drastically decreased performance.

While my trans-coder is working the whole system is lagging. I must change the go task's priority to low or idle to be able to work again.

How could I implement something that keeps the system responsive?

Right now I start thousands of go-routines (loop over a slice of pointers). Should I limit the number of routines?

Comment: There is not pount in having much more runnable goroutines than cores, so yes: limit them. Decrease GOMAXPROCS to limit how many threads and thus cores you program will use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lowering the process priority is arguably the *correct* way to do this. Use your OS's scheduler. That's what it's for. [Per this question](https://superuser.com/questions/699651/start-process-in-high-priority) you can start your process with a specified priority like so:

```
start "MyApp" /low "C:\myapp.exe"
```

You *may* also be able to set process priority from within the application [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928541/how-to-change-process-application-priority-from-normal-to-low-programmatically):

```
err := syscall.Setpriority(syscall.Getpid(), -1, -1)
```

Lastly, you can use `GOMAXPROCS` to configure how many CPUs the process is allowed to use. You can pass it in as an environment variable at runtime, or call [`runtime.GOMAXPROCS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) within your code to override it.

Comment: so i should outsource the part that does the translation and start it from main with some kind of loader with a given priority? like gui+jobs+solver?

Comment: That depends entirely on your needs. Do whatever works for your situation. If running the whole thing at lowered priority works, I don't see any reason to make it more complicated than that.

Comment: i just would like to skip the manual priority decrease via task manager to let it be as userfriendly as possible. the most simple but ugly solution could be a clickme.cmd that starts the exe with prio below normal... but that's not smart.

Comment: Updated with more options.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the simplest solution is to limit the number of concurrent goroutines using a semaphore, for example:

```
sem := make(chan int, 10) // limited at go routines 

for {
    sem <- 1
    go doThis()
}

func doThis() {
    //do this
    <- sem
}
```

The "sem <- 1" inside the for loop blocks until a goroutine "slot" is freed up by doThis extracting something from the sem channel/